# Backtrace on file open

Tags: files, backtrace

I am curious about the origin of certain files under `~/.emacs.d`, such as: `places`, `url/cookies`, `tramp`, `eshell/history`, `eshell/lastdir`, `auto-save-list/.saves-15234-mymachine~`, `request/curl-cookie-jar`.

I'd like to know not only where they came from, but what variable I need to set in order to relocate them to other locations of my choosing.

To further my investigation of these files, I'd like to get a backtrace from Emacs when it opens any of them (or any other files of my choosing).  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Can you give examples (names) of such files? Are you talking about auto-save files (`#...#`)? backup files (`...~`, `...~999~`)?

Comment: All of the following under `~/.emacs.d`: `places`, `url/cookies`, `tramp`, `eshell/history`, `eshell/lastdir`, `auto-save-list/.saves-15234-mymachine~`, `request/curl-cookie-jar`.  I can guess that `tramp` comes from using TRAMP, but what variable do I need to change to have it be created somewhere else instead?  Same with the rest.  I'd like to track these down in the general case by looking at backtraces when they're opened.

Comment: Please put all such relevant info in the question. Comments can be deleted at any time.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want to do this?  The `~/.emacs.d` directory is *supposed* to contain such things.  Some are configurable, but you may not be able to relocate all such files without modifying the libraries in question.  A few such cases may support "old" alternative filenames in the HOME directory, via the `OLD-NAME` argument to `locate-user-emacs-file`, in which cases you could move the file from its `~/.emacs.d` location to its old name, and it would still be used; but the modern intention is that such files and directories live under `~/.emacs.d/`.

Comment: @phils: Many reasons.  First, because it's an awful mess in there.  Whenever I need to troubleshoot anything or figure out why something is where it is or change something I have no idea why these files are in there or how they affect Emacs or what package they belong to even.  I like [no-littering's](https://github.com/Fuco1/no-littering) suggestion of prefixing every filename with the respective package name, but even that alone is not enough for me.  I want control over where every file lives... (continued in next comment)

Comment: @phils: I have a lot of my own files in `~/.emacs.d` and don't want them mixed up with some random files dumped in there by random packages that I use.  Also, I like to version control my entire `~/.emacs.d` and eventually throw it up on github for public consumption.  But that's not very wise when some of the automatically generated files in `~/.emacs.d` contain all sorts of sensitive information (from cookies to browsing history, etc).  So I want those in a private directory that I specify.  But some other things can stay somewhere under `~/.emacs.d` in a subdirectory of my choosing.

Comment: FWIW, `.gitignore` is your friend.

Comment: Also FWIW, if your put all those files of your own in a suitably-named sub-directory, that's a much simpler way to prevent them being mixed up with the files written by Emacs libraries.

Answer (score 1):

The [advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) framework is good for this sort of thing.  You could advise low-level functions like `write-region` and `insert-file-contents` (those probably offer good coverage).  One way would be to use a function that logs both the filename and a stack trace.  Something like the following:

```
(advice-add
 #'insert-file-contents :before
 (lambda (&rest args)
   (message "Interesting function called with args: %s" args)
   (backtrace)))
```

This will probably give you a /lot/ of output in your `*Messages*` buffer, so a more conservative function might be needed.

Comment: But I don't want to log on every file access, but only when certain specific files are opened (when they're first opened, ideally).  Could I do that?

Comment: @izkon Sure.  You could track filenames by adding them to a list or hashtable.  You could also use a function like `f-child-of-p` (from the `f` package) to filter your logging as well.  It sounds like you just want to explore though (a one-time thing?), so I personally would just search through the messages buffer.

Comment: `f-child-of-p` check to see if one path is a child of another path.  I'm not sure I understand how that helps.

Comment: @izkon I mention that since you said "certain files under ~/.emacs.d".  A predicate like that might offer a useful constraint.  If you advise `insert-file-contents` the first argument is the filename, so you could condition your advise logging on that filename meeting some criteria like `(when (f-child-of-p filename "~/.emacs.d") ...` to only log if it's a file immediately inside your init folder.